# Displaying user specific Form Fields in TCA TYPO3

Tags: forms, typo3, backend

Is there a way I can change the Form fields and options depending on the current user?

Like for instance, if the current user is just a Simple_User he/she should not be shown the option "evaluate". But for an Admin, the evaluate option should be available.

How can I achieve this using TCA for creating backend forms for a plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the TCA there is the option "exclude", which gives you the option to set the permission for BackendUser or BackendGroup if the user is allowed to view/edit the field.